# Is this picture of Trump making people swear to vote for him genuine?

Tags: united-states, politics, donald-trump

From https://twitter.com/wpjenna/status/706227458777993216 (5K retweets, Washington Post reporter, verified user)

> [image: Image used in tweet]
>
> Donald Trump makes members of his Orlando crowd raise their right
>   hands and swear to vote in the primary.

Are the people holding up their arms to swear to vote for him, as opposed to, say, raising their hand to agree or disagree with a question he asked?

Comment: @Downvoter: I genuinely suspected someone making a bogus claim about him, because lots of people dislike him.

Comment: I don't have an original source but I read he was getting people to promise to vote in the primary.

Comment: Note that the photo caption says he is having the crowd "swear to vote in the primary", not that he is having them swear to vote _for him_ in the primary.

Comment: It's common for candidates to ask people to pledge to vote for them, and even sign their name to that effect. Such pledges are not legally binding. So it's not the least bit surprising that Trump would do the same.

Comment: @Flimzy do they raise their hands like this doing so?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - many public speakers do the "raise your hand if ..." trick. It's a trick to give the audience some interactive participation. And/or to visualize the level of support for something. You do the same things in computer science lectures, so no evil political overtones are inherent in the approach.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: Why not? It's certainly within the realm of "completely obvious" that they would.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm In all fairness, it should be said that Trump did not ask the people to do the hitler salute, and when he himself raised his hand, it looked like the normal swear-handraising. Although it may not be the best idea asking his followers to raise their right hand...

Comment: +4/-3? If the Donald were asking this he'd ask something inflammatory and be getting dozens of upvotes and downvotes and the rep gain would be yuge!

Comment: @user5341 I was thinking of that possibility when asking the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I haven't got an exact match of the picture with any videos, but there is [video evidence of him](https://youtu.be/YBLmh8ck0yk?t=24s) asking people to swear to vote for him.

Comment: your video isn't working, but the Orlando pledge is at 57 minutes in this video https://www.c-span.org/video/?406060-1/donald-trump-campaign-rally-orlando-florida and the screen shot in the OP is from the video embedded here: https://thehill.com/blogs/ballot-box/presidential-races/271932-trump-makes-rally-attendees-swear-to-vote-for-him